# In Java what's the fastest and easiest way to convert an array of String into an array of float?

Tags: java, arrays, string, floating-point, type-conversion

I have something like this :

```
 String text[]="5.75,9.05,8.16,0.94,-0.10,-0.56,3.60".split(",");
```

And now I'm doing this to convert it to an array of float :

```
float f[]=new float[text.length];
for (int i=0;i<f.length;i++)
    f[i]=Float.parseFloat(text[i]);
```

I wonder if there is a one liner to do something like this :

`float f[]=(float)text[]`?

Comment: An array of `String`(s) or one `String`? And are you using Java 8?

Comment: since when a String can be converted to an array of type String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're using Java 8, this is the fastest and easiest way to do what you need.

If you're using Java 8, you can do the following one liner:

```
Float f[] = Arrays.stream(text).map(t -> Float.parseFloat(t)).toArray(Float[]::new);
```

Comment: When I compiled it, got this : error: incompatible types: Object[] cannot be converted to float[]

Comment: @Frank - I just updated the answer with something that should fix the compiler error. That's what I get for being a C# developer instead of Java. I assumed that Java could infer the type of the array from the generics. Unfortunately `toArray` without a generator return `Object[]`.

Comment: Thanks, great. I wonder if you know which is faster/more efficient, my solution or yours ?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that your original code is probably a hair faster as I'm not sure of the internals of `Stream.map` as well as if `toArray` involves resizing the array at any point internally.

Answer (score 1):

In `Java 8`

**Code**:

```
    String text = "5.75,9.05,8.16,0.94,-0.10,-0.56,3.60 ";
    String[] spText = text.split(",");
    List<Float> list = Stream.of(spText)
            .map(f -> Float.parseFloat(f))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    list.forEach(f -> System.out.print(" " + f));
```

**Output**:

```
5.75 9.05 8.16 0.94 -0.1 -0.56 3.6
```

**Explanation**:

Stream class accept a array and you parse all String to float type one by one and you collect them in to a list which has type Float and print them out

**One issue**:

a String can be converted to an array of type String.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable
> source code - **incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted
> to java.lang.String[]**

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 you should be able to the following:

```
    float f[] = Arrays.stream(text).map(Float::parseFloat).toArray(Float[]::new);
```

Comment: When I compiled it, got this : error: incompatible types: Object[] cannot be converted to float[]

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! Justin Niessner's answer above took care of it as you've already seen, and I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

First things first: while it is legal to declare an array using brackets after the variable's name, it is not recommended to do so. The following is the generally accepted way:

```
String[] text;
```

Also, I'm pretty sure you haven't ran your code through a compiler, since your syntax for creating your array isn't correct. The following is one of the correct ways to initialize an array:

```
String[] text = new String[]{"5.75", "9.05", "8.16", "0.94", "-0.10", "-0.56", "3.60"};
```

Now, to convert your String elements to float use the following:

```
String[] text = new String[]{"5.75", "9.05", "8.16", "0.94", "-0.10", "-0.56", "3.60"};
Float[] f = new Float[text.length];
Arrays.stream(text).map(Float::parseFloat).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(f);
```